# How to take a cube root in Go?

Tags: go

I'm writing a cube root function in Google Go using Newton's method. I want to check the results using math/`cmplx.Pow()`, but for the life of me, I can't figure out how. How do I do this?

Comment: Not worth another answer but for completeness, if you can compute exp(y), y=log(x)/3 you are good with those two functions:

x^{1/3} = exp(log(x^{1/3})) = exp((1/3) log(x))

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you tried `myCubicRootOfx = Pow(x, 1.0/3)` ?

**edited**: thanks to `Jason McCreary` comment:
We cannot use `1/3` as the 2nd parameter to `Pow` as this is a integer division and hence doesn't produce the expected 1/3 value.  By using `1.0/3` or `1/3.0` etc. we effectively produce a float with the 0.333333... value.

Comment: Doesn't get much simpler than that! +1

Comment: Needs to be `1.0/3.0` to prevent integer division.

Comment: This is the right answer unless you are in a hurry. If you need to call this millions of times per frame or second, then pow() can be slow. Compare the speed of sqrt(x) vs pow(x,1/2.0). If you know the argument range, and also know what accuracy you need, you can do better than pow()

Answer (score 9):

I wrote the cube root function using Newton's method as part of the [Go Tour Exercise 47](http://tour.golang.org/#47). Perhaps the two functions below (`Cbrt1` and `Cbrt`) are helpful.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/cmplx"
)

// Newton's method cube root function that hopes for
//   convergence within 20 iterations
func Cbrt1(x complex128) complex128 {
    var z complex128 = x
    for i:= 0; i < 20; i++ {
        z = z - ((z*z*z - x) / (3.0*z*z))
    }
    return z
}

// Newton's method cube root function that runs until stable
func Cbrt(x complex128) complex128 {
    var z, z0 complex128 = x, x
    for {
        z = z - ((z*z*z - x) / (3.0*z*z))
        if cmplx.Abs(z - z0) < 1e-10 {
            break
        }
        z0 = z
    }
    return z
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Cbrt(2.0) , "should match" , cmplx.Pow(2, 1.0/3.0))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you're using Newton's method, I suppose you're starting with a positive real number.

So you don't need complex numbers.

You may simply do

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    x := 100.0
    root := math.Pow(x, 1.0/3.0)
    fmt.Println(root)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like go has changed more recently than some of the other answers, so I figured I would update - they built cuberoot right into `math` as `Cbrt`. It takes, and returns, a `float64`. A quick reference is at `godoc math | grep Cbrt` (if you've got `godoc` installed, which I highly recommend)

```
import "math"

func main() {
    var x float64 = math.Cbrt(8)
    fmt.Println(x) // prints 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/cmplx"
)

func main() {
    var x complex128
    x = -8
    y := cmplx.Pow(x, 1.0/3.0)
    fmt.Println(y)
    x = -27i
    y = cmplx.Pow(x, 1.0/3.0)
    fmt.Println(y)
    x = -8 - 27i
    y = cmplx.Pow(x, 1.0/3.0)
    fmt.Println(y)
    x = complex(-8, -27)
    y = cmplx.Pow(x, 1.0/3.0)
    fmt.Println(y)
}
```

Output:

```
(1+1.732050807568877i)
(2.5980762113533156-1.4999999999999996i)
(2.4767967587776756-1.7667767800295509i)
(2.4767967587776756-1.7667767800295509i)
```

[The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)

[Package cmplx](http://golang.org/pkg/math/cmplx/)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
package main

import(
        "fmt"
        "math/cmplx"
    )


func Cbrt(x complex128) complex128 {
    z := complex128(1)


    for i:=0;i<100;i++ {  // OR JUST for{ since you will outrun complex128 in worth case
      last_z := z

      z = z - ((z*z*z - x)/(3 *z*z))    
      if last_z == z{
        return z
      }
    }
    return z
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("good enough", Cbrt(9))
    fmt.Println("builtin", cmplx.Pow(9, 1.0/3.0))
}
```

Comment: Whenever I read an answer with “try (something like) this” and throws out a bunch of code I have to ask (myself) “why?”. Please provide some information what your code does, what it accomplishes, and what the “something like” variance points to.